# simplify expressions into sum function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to have Mathematica simplify long expressions involving sums of variables into expressions using a sum function? Suppose I have something like this:

```
Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[x, 3] + Subscript[x, 
  4] + Subscript[x, 5]
```

I would like to get the following output after simplification:

```
Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: In fact, the reverse happens by default.  `Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 5}]` returns `Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[x, 3] + Subscript[x, 4] + Subscript[x, 5]`.  The same is true for `Sum[x[i], {i, 5}]`.

Comment: Yes, and this is particularly unfortunate when differentiating or integrating sums, like `D[Sum[x^i, {i, 1, 10}], x]`. In some cases it would be nice if sums weren't expanded automatically.